# Kohana Select order by

Tags: kohana

Sometimes when I refresh page the events I have sorts them DESCENDING by date, but I need ascending order by time.

http://prntscr.com/bubuz5

http://prntscr.com/bubvad

Code

```
public function get_frontpage_events() 
{
    return DB::select()->
                from('events')->
                where_open()->
                where('frontpage', '=', 1)->
                where('status', '=', 1)->
                where('lang', '=', Session::instance()->get('lang'))->
                where_close()->
                order_by('date', 'ASC')->order_by('time', 'ASC')->
                execute()->
                as_array();
}
```

Comment: What about to change date and time columns into one datetime and use only than columns. With PHP functions you can get date and time from this data type anytime.

Answer (score 0):

**You query looks fine.**

I don't know if you have a query log, but if you have you can check what query is executed, copy and paste it and run it yourself. The above code should create this SQL query (my guess is you are using MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE (`frontpage` = 1 AND `status` = 1 AND `lang` = 'EN') ORDER BY `date` ASC, `time` ASC
```

Do you do some other ordering/sorting in your view or your controller? When you loop over your results, are you sure you display all results?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be in **order_by()->order_by()** syntax. This method allows to use array in first argument, try this:

```
order_by(array('date','time'), 'ASC')
```